# How to exclude login route from authentication middleware in Silex?

Tags: silex

I made a middleware to authenticate users before every request and applied it in the beginning of the whole app.

`$app->before(function($request, $app) {
    Auth::authenticate($request, $app);
});`

But it also applied to the login route how to fix this? 
 it's a Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware is being run before all routes. So, you've probably got a route like this:

```
$routes->match('/login', function () use ($app) {
    // Login etc.
});
```

Or you're using, GET of POST or whatever. The middleware will always be run before a route is being run. So yes, your middleware is also applied before the login since it works for every route.

You could fix it by running the middleware after your login route like this:

```
$routes->match('/login', function () use ($app) {
    // Login etc.
})
->after($after);
```

More details on this can be found [here](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/middlewares.html#id2)!

You could also change your middleware so that it first checks whether the user is logged in already. If so, run the authentication, if not... do nothing.

```
$app->before(function($request, $app) {
    if user is logged in {
        Auth::authenticate($request, $app);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps you out. Don't forget to mark as completed when it does the job for you, otherwise, please leave a comment or edit your question and I'll help you out!

Comment: your last example means that it won't authenticate if it is NOT logged in, I want to authenticate in both cases but the  problem is when the login route fired and it requires auth header and token also and that is wrong I need a way to exclude the login route and I don't want to repeat myself and do it manually for every route, my problem is the login route